# It does not show the map (google maps) in my controller.

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var containView: UIView!

let locManager=CLLocationManager()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.locManager.delegate = self
        self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
        self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func showCurrentLocationOnMap() {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 140)

        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = "Current location"
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        marker.map = mapView
        self.containView.addSubview(mapView)

    }
```

I added this code in my controller because i'm trying to display the map (google maps) with a marker on my current location but is not working (the map is not shown), what i did wrong in my code? How can i fix it?

Comment: is `locationManager` function being called? are you testing on the simulator?

Comment: i'm testing on device

Comment: is `locationManager` being called? add for example a breakpoint on the function or change the function to accept latitude e longitude and call it from viewdidload

Comment: FTF, when you run your app for first time it won't run properly, for sure. You have `self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` and `self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in a sequence. But `self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is an async function, so the first time, user has not authorized location yet, thus, `self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()` won't execute. About your map, I can't see any map reference on your code, are you inserting it on IB ?

Comment: @GIJOW yeah, maybe is that the problem, how can i fix it to execute self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation() ? About your question now my code is like on claudio answer but it still do not work

Comment: I would use `didChangeAuthorization` delegate method, check whether the user has authorized or not and startUpdating locations. In your `viewDidLoad` you can check the auth status and call `self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or `self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()` accordingly using `switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus())` for example. Ideally I would need to post in the answer it, but as I can't figure out why you don't see the map, I will let it in comments for while

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you setting the `containView` type on the interface builder, like this, also change the name to `mapView` (to be clear), be aware of the type `GMSMapView` and link it to your `CourseClass2` controller:

[image: Interface builder]
(I'm not on a Mac so I used this image. Image source: http://vikrambahl.com/google-maps-ios-xcode-storyboards/)

And try using the following code, at least the map (without marker) should appear.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

let locManager=CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locManager.delegate = self
    self.locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    self.showCurrentLocationOnMap()
    self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func showCurrentLocationOnMap() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 140)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = camera.target
    marker.snippet = "Current location"
    marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Also be carefull with force unwrapping optionals `(self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!` as it might cause fatal errors

Comment: this only show the map but all the code still do not work :(

Comment: @fisherM that's probably because the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` is not being called/triggered by the system which means that the marker won't show

Comment: any idea of how can i fix it?

Comment: @fisherM you add the permission in info.plist?

Comment: @KhawarIslam  yes i added

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 9.2 & Swift 4**

Go to your info.plist file and add the following key according to your code.

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```

Move to your View controller and replace the showCurrentLocationOnMap() function with this code.

```
 func showCurrentLocationOnMap() {

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, zoom: 10.0)

        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = "Current location"
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        marker.map = mapView
        self.view = mapView

    }
```

Run the code in Simulator **Debug->Location->Apple** choose or Apple Device. My simulator image with your code.
[image]